# Is the space of all eventually constant sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ be Banach Space with respect to sup-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory

Let $W$ be the collection of all eventually constant sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Is the space $W$ be Banach Space with respect to sup-norm?

We know that collection of all convergent sequences $C$ is a Banach Space with respect to sup-norm. To show $W$ is Banach, It is enough to show that $W$ is closed subspace of $C$ with respect to sup-norm.
Let $\{x^n\}$ be a sequance in $W$ such that $x^n\to x$ , where $x^n=(x^n_i)$ and $x=(x_i)$.
To show $W$ is closed, we need to show that $x\in W.$  As $x^n\to x$, corresponding to a preassigned positive number $\epsilon>0$, there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x^n-x\|_\infty<\epsilon,$ for all $n\geq k.$  Therefore $|x_i^n-x_i|<\epsilon$ for each $i\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq k.$
Note that $x^{k}=(x^k_i)$ is eventually constant sequence. then there exists $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^k_i=t_0$ for some $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $i\geq p.$
Now for $i,j\geq p$

$|x_i-x_j|\leq |x_i-x_i^k|+|x_i^k-x_j^k|+|x_j^k-x_j|< 2 \epsilon$ .

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitary positive real number, $x_i=x_j$ for all $i,j\geq p.$ hence $x=(x_i)$ is eventually constant. Therefore $x\in W.$ Hence $W$ is closed in $C$ with respect to sup-norm. Since $C$ is Banach with respect to sup-norm, $W$  is Banach.

Please let me know if anything wrong in the above arguments.

Comment: $x^k$ and $p$ depends in general on $\epsilon$

Comment: The sequence $n^{-1}$ is the uniform limit of eventually constant sequences

Comment: Yes the sequences $(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$, $(1, \frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$, $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ should converge to $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ which falls outside $W$.

Comment: Thank you @0XLR

Comment: Thank you @RyszardSzwarc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as noted in the comments, $W$ is not complete.  Let $(a_n)_n$ be a not-eventually-constant sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.  Then the "stop at $k$ and repeat" sequences
$$
(a^{(k)}_n)_n, \quad a^{(k)}_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
a_n& n<k\\
a_k&n\geq k\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
or "stop at $k$ and repeat zero" sequences
$$
(a^{(k)}_n)_n, \quad a^{(k)}_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
a_n& n<k\\
0&n\geq k\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
are eventually constant (constant after index $k$) and converge to the original sequence $(a_n)_n$ in the sup norm,
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\|a-a^{(k)}\|_{\infty}=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

This set has a countable basis consisting of the unit vectors
$$
e_k = (0, \dots ,0, 1, 0, \dots)
$$
and the vectors
$$
f_k = (0,\dots, 0, 1,1,\dots)
$$
for $k\in \mathbb N$.
Due to the Baire theorem, the resulting space is not complete with respect to any norm.